# Is it bad practice to use SignalR solely to trigger local update methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, signalr

I've been integrating SignalR into a couple of my Angular projects and have been wondering whether it would be such a bad idea to use SignalR only to trigger updates in my apps as opposed to sending actual data via the connection.

Obviously there are benefits to sending the actual data over SignalR, but I am just not confident that it has to be done this way in all cases, and whether it would be terrible of me to use it only to trigger update methods being called in my MCV app.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This question is far too vague

Comment: The answer to this question would be almost all opinion based.

Comment: It enables a two way communication, if your app only needs one way communication, you could use Server Side Events instead, but IMHO, no problems